# Write PDF based on elements position

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf, pypdf

I need to generate a PDF based on an array of elements that contains the box of the text, like so:

```
arr = [{'text':'Hello World',
'position':
{'width':130,
'height':20,
'top':20,
'left':300}},
...]
```

I am using python and have tested FPDF:

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
for el in arr:
    pdf.cell(el['position']['width'], el['position']['height'],txt=el['text'], align="C")
pdf.output("simple_demo.pdf")
```

Problem is I have no info on line breaks, only the positions of the elements on the document.
Any idea on how to plot the texts on the PDF based on position?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why do you need info on line breaks?

Comment: @ThomasSablik with my current approach I dont have the position to place the text on other TOPs, it just place all strings on first line

Comment: You have a list of text elements containing a position. Why are the positions not correct? Where do they come from?

Comment: I have no option with fpdf to write based on position.

Comment: You should change the tags. FPDF is a PHP library. pypdf2 seems to be a different library. You are using pyfpdf. You should read the tutorial https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html. _A cell is a rectangular area, possibly framed, which contains some text. It is output __at the current position__._

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your current position:

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
for el in arr:
    pdf.set_xy(el['position']['left'], el['position']['top'])
    pdf.cell(el['position']['width'], el['position']['height'],txt=el['text'], align="C")
pdf.output("simple_demo.pdf")
```